Refining a Tikzpicture Fading Color Background
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.625in,paperheight=8.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}

\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{102,0,0}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [top color=black, middle color=DarkRed!40!black, bottom color=DarkRed!90!black] (current page.south west)rectangle (current page.north east);   
 \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\par \emph{}
\end{document}

which produces

For some reason, to obtain the picture, I had to compile twice.
The above TIKZ fading color background has three different colors: (1) top color, (2) middle color, and (3) bottom color.
QUESTION: How may I increase the number of fadings to, say, five---occurring in equal intervals from top to bottom---starting with black and fading all the way down to DarkRed!85!black?
Thank you.

either use two shadings with three colours each where the third and first colours are identical or define a custom shading. note that there is a difference between a fading and a shading. (sort of, anyway. the manual uses the terms differently.) you always have to compile twice if you use remember picture.

do you get warnings telling you not to use everypage for new documents? I also need 3 compilations rather than 2. I also don't need remember picture, overlay. I seem to remember background already takes care of this.

The simplest approach from an end-user perspective is to just use two shadings with matching colours. For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (+5cm,0pt);
  \fill [top color=cyan,bottom color=red,middle color=green] (0pt,5cm) rectangle (5cm,0pt);
  \fill [top color=red,bottom color=blue,middle color=magenta] (0pt,0pt) rectangle (5cm,-5cm);
\draw [densely dashed,thin,white] (0,0) -- (5cm,0pt) (0pt,2.5cm) -- (5cm,2.5cm) (0pt,-2.5cm) -- (5cm,-2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This locates the set-colour points at equal distances. It does not make the areas affected by those set-colour points equal. This is the same as the case of the standard three-colour case: the middle colour is equidistant from the other two and, hence, has a disproportionate effect on the space as a whole. Essentially, the middle colour shades both up and down, whereas the top and bottom colours shade either down or up. In the case of five colours and two shadings, the middle three colours shade both up and down.

